# PCL visualizer addPointCloud() crashes

Tags: qt, visualization, printer-control-language

I'm trying to create a simple application using QT to display point clouds. However the PCL visualizer crashes at

```
pviz.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud_xyz,"cloud1");
```

Is there are initializations that I am missing?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer pviz ("test_viz");
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_xyz (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    for (float y = -0.5f; y <= 0.5f; y += 0.01f)
    {
        for (float z = -0.5f; z <= 0.5f; z += 0.01f)
        {
            pcl::PointXYZ point;
            point.x = 2.0f - y;
            point.y = y;
            point.z = z;
            cloud_xyz->points.push_back (point);
        }
    }
    cloud_xyz->width = cloud_xyz->points.size ();
    cloud_xyz->height = 1;
    std::cerr<<"Cloud Gen";
    pviz.addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud_xyz,"cloud1");
     std::cerr<<"Cloud Add";
    pviz.setBackgroundColor(0, 0, 0.1);
    pviz.initCameraParameters();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**The is just a demo program, hence I just want to add the point cloud and I haven't kept it in a loop or a separate thread.**

Comment: @Exa could you help me out?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PCL Visualizer unfortunately. I saw some reports on errors when using VS2015 and this method, but didn't find a solution.

Comment: The solution is not to use PCL visualizer, but to directly render it using VTK.

Comment: There is not nearly enough information to answer the question.  @Leroy Francisco Pereira is correct.  You should be using a VTK widget and linking the interactor and renderer to the visualizer.  But getting PCL compiled and linked properly IS HARD.  It's like 6 different libraries that need to be compiled and linked with a compatable QT build.  The are hundreds of things that could be wrong.

Comment: But if you wanted this example to work, you would need pviz.Spin() somwhere.  But that can't be in your main thread unless you want it to block.  You do need to use a VTKWidget in side a QGUI application to get what you want.  there seems to be so much wrong with this lol.

Comment: @Exa, I have gotten PCL 1.8 working with visual studio 2015.  I basically had to build and link all the libraries individually.  It works well, I haven't run into any impassible errors.

Comment: same problem with pcl1.8, vtk5.8 and ubuntu14.04